# Animate certain ListView items

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-arrayadapter

My goal is to animate certain `ListView` items without having to worry about `getView` messing with the animations by replacing list items with newly inflated ones in the custom `ArrayAdapter`.

If I use `convertView` to avoid inflating new items the order of the animations changes randomly.

Caching the views manually works fine but I doubt that it is a good solution. Better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is to set animation at convertview and then I stop animation on each convertview. This way the animation is stopped and then played if the convertview is new and continue until end if it isn't recycled before it ends.

**Edit** I can't seem to find an example so it will be partly pseudo code.

In your adapter you'll have something like following:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        // setup holder
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = Inflater.inflate(mResourceId, null);

        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
        holder.headline = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_headline);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // get existing row view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // GetView is only called on new items 
    // so now we stop the previous animation and start a new
    holder.animation.stop();  // First you stop the animation
    holder.animation = new animation();  // then you create new
    holder.animation.start();  // then you start the animation.
```

Comment: @AshrafSayied-Ahmad I added a little example, its not perfect but you get the jest of it.